# Plot histogram percentages with ruby

Tags: ruby, gnuplot, histogram

Suppose I have a file with a percetage for each row, like this:

```
0.86
0.456
0.4389
0.56
0.69
0.468
0.46
0.368
0.9
...
```

I want to plot an histogram with these data in a Ruby script using `gnuplot` gem.
It may looks like a Gauss bell.

How can I do this?

Comment: Reading the documentation sounds like a good place to start… Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Denis, yes I have, but ruby acts like a wrappers so I do not know how to specify some options. Thanks.

Comment: Methinks rephrase the question to show what you tried and why it's not working...

Answer (score 2):

I had some fun trying out the gnuplot gem :)

Given a file `data.txt` like this one

```
0.86
0.456
0.4389
0.56
0.69
0.468
0.46
0.368
0.9
```

This Ruby class should do the trick:

```
require 'gnuplot'

class DataPlotter
  class << self
    def plot_data(data)
      Gnuplot.open do |gp|
        Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
          plot.title  "Data Plot Example"
          plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new(data) do |ds|
            ds.with = "linespoints"
            ds.notitle
          end
        end
      end
    end

    def load_data_from_file(filename)
      File.open(filename).readlines.map do |line|
        line.chomp.to_f
      end
    end

    def plot_file(filename)
      plot_data(load_data_from_file(filename))
    end
  end
end

DataPlotter.plot_file('data.txt')
```

Gives this result:

[image]